# Differnece Between MYSQL(Binary) and MySql in LAMP/WAMP/MAMP

Tags: mysql, wamp, mamp, lamp, wampserver

1. What is difference between MySQL(Binary) and MySql in (LAMP,MAMP, WAMP) ?
2. Which one is better to use?
3. On What Criteria  i should select one of them?

> Regardless of Operating System.
>   Which of mysql will be better to use for web as well as standalone development.

Comment: Fairly sure I dont understand the question. Are you asking which OS should you use?

Comment: Are you talking about a development environment?

Comment: Then what are you developing with? Normally one doesn't use MySQL in isolation.

Comment: I have to implement One sample project which show basic functionality of Database using Java and just for learning purpose i want to convert that project on web as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking,

1. There is no appreciable difference between `MySQL` running on Windows/Linux/Mac environments.
2. Whichever you find easiest.
3. As a windows user I develop using WampServer on a windows PC, that gets me Apache/MySQL and PHP all in one easy to install package. However it is normal and in many ways preferable to use a *nix  environment for implementing your LIVE website on.